Running PyInstaller on Streamlit app: [Errno13] Permission denied
I have created an streamlit web app in VS Code that runs perfectly fun when I run it using "streamlit run app.py" from Powershell. I have some .pkl files that the app needs access to. The files are in a "artifacts" directory alongside app.py. I have included them in app.py like this:
#app.py

artifacts_dir = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'artifacts')

model_path = os.path.join(artifacts_dir, 'model.pkl')
books_name_path = os.path.join(artifacts_dir, 'books_name.pkl')
final_rating_path = os.path.join(artifacts_dir, 'final_rating.pkl')
book_pivot_path = os.path.join(artifacts_dir, 'book_pivot.pkl')

with open(model_path, 'rb') as file:
        model = pickle.load(file)
    with open(books_name_path, 'rb') as file:
        books_name = pickle.load(file)
    with open(final_rating_path, 'rb') as file:
        final_rating = pickle.load(file)
    with open(book_pivot_path, 'rb') as file:
        book_pivot = pickle.load(file)

I run PyInstaller with this command: "pyinstaller app.spec"
I include the artifacts folder in app.spec like this:
#app.spec

def get_all_files_in_directory(directory):
    paths = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            full_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            relative_path = os.path.relpath(full_path, '.')
            paths.append((full_path, relative_path))
    return paths

datas = get_all_files_in_directory('artifacts')

a = Analysis(
    ...
    datas=datas,
    ...
)

The exe builds just fine, but when I run it, I keep getting this error:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\tyler\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI31922\\artifacts\\model.pkl'
I tried running the exe as administrator, and it still gave the same error. Checked the permissions on each directory in that path and ensured that every user has read access to them, but that didn't fix the problem either. I'm not sure what else to try.
